# Can I open a project using .Net framework 3.5 in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

Can I open a website project using .net framework 3.5 in visual studio 2015 community? Lastly, what framework does the visual studio 2015 community supports?

As of now, I don't have visual studio 2015 installed in my pc. but i will install. 
Thanks:) I hope someone answer my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 was released at the same time as  .Net 4.6
They are designed and released together.

You will be able to open a .net framework 3.5 website.